# JsRender/JsViews: How to get {for} working for subclassed arrays

Tags: typescript, jsrender, jsviews

I've subclassed Array (using TypeScript), in order to be able to add extra functions to the Array. See code below.

Since then, I've noticed that the `{for}` tag of JsRender/JsViews does not work any more.
I've also noticed JsRender/JsViews uses `$.isArray(...)` in order to iterate arrays, which will return `false` on subclassed arrays.

When I change JsRender/JsViews code to use `(data instanceof Array)` it does work.

Is there another way (without changing JsRender/JsViews code) to get subclassed arrays to work with JsRender/JsViews `{for}` tag?

**Typescript:**

```
module MyModule {
    export class Collection<T> implements Array<T> {
        constructor() {
            Array.apply(this, arguments);
            return new Array();
        }

        length: number;
        toString(): string { return ""; }
        //... All other Array properties/methods
    }

    // replace dummy declarations with the real thing
    Collection['prototype'] = new Array();
}
```

**Generated Javascript:**

```
var MyModule;
(function (MyModule) {
    var Collection = (function () {
        function Collection() {
            Array.apply(this, arguments);
            return new Array();
        }

        Collection.prototype.toString = function () { return ""; };
        //... All other Array properties/methods

        return Collection;
    })();
    MyModule.Collection = Collection;

    // replace dummy declarations with the real thing
    Collection['prototype'] = new Array();
})(MyModule|| (MyModule= {}));
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. Are you using the latest jQuery and JsViews?

Comment: I was using JQuery 1.9.1. I've updated to 2.1.3, however it's still not working. I Just realised the issue is a bit more complicated. The reason I subclassed Array into Collection<T> is so that I can subclass Collection<T> as well. For instance: `class NumberCollection extends Collection<number>`. I've created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkLttzg4/) to illustrate the issue. When using Collection it works, but when using SubclassedCollection it doesn't. As I mentioned above: I got it to work when changing JsView to use `(data instanceof Array)` instead of `$.isArray(data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SubclassedCollection is not a JavaScript array (just as a jQuery object is not a JavaScript array). Unlike your Collection, it returns `"[object Object]"` from `Object.prototype.toString.call(ob)` - rather than `"[object Array]"`.

One possible approach might be to use the function:

```
function toArray(ob) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(ob);
}
```

and either write

```
MyModule.ViewModel = { Coll: toArray(collection2) };
```

or else register `toArray` as a helper (`~toArray`) or a converter (`"toArray"`) and then write your template as:

```
{{for ~toArray(Coll)}}
```

(or alternatively `{{for Coll convert=~toArray}}` or `{{for Coll convert="toArray"}}`).

Here is an updated fork of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16L670re/